# Javascript split returning unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable which I need to split into 3.

This is how it looks:

```
message = "save 'this is a message content' 'path here' ";
```

So the save would be `msg[0]` the content would be inside `msg[1]` etc

So I've done this split:

```
var msg = message.split('')[1];

console.log(msg);
```

But it's returning `error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token` this, and I have the feeling the split code it not right?

How can I do this?

Comment: `But it's returning split returning unexpected token` What do you mean? It's returning `a` which is correct as arrays start at 0. Did you mean to split on `'`?

Comment: @Paul Zone Please add more code

Comment: The code you gave is valid, error is somewhere else

Comment: Changed the question

Comment: @PaulZone shouldn't it be `message.split(' ')[1];
` instead of `message.split('')[1];
`?

Comment: @nickzoum I think `message.split('\'')[1]` is actually what they want

Comment: The code as posted would not and does not produce the error you say it does. Some other code might, of course, but not the code actually in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the split is wrong, by splitting this way, the `msg` will contain every character of the message. you can try this way;

```
msg = message.split("'")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

`var aMessage = sMessage.split("'").filter((sText)=>{ return sText.trim(); })`

After `split()`ing you get strings with the spaces ' '. You `filter()` those because they `trim()` to empty string / false.

EDIT:
There's also a space after 'save ', so you could add `.map((sText)=>sText.trim())` after the filter.

For debugging your stuff I find `JSON.stringify()` is essential:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: He said he is getting error. `error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Comment: Probably due to the space at the end. I updated my answer.